# dismissViewController doesn't dismiss presented view controller when using universal storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have discovered a situation that causes `dismissViewController:animated:completion` to not dismiss the view controller that has been presented. While it does dismiss on iPad running iOS 8, it doesn't dismiss on iPad running iOS 7.1. I've tried `self`, `self.presentingViewController`, and `self.presentedViewController` - all do nothing. I've tried it with Xcode 6.0 and 6.1 beta. While I do believe this is a bug, what can be done to work around it and force dismiss that view controller, ensuring it will work for iPad running iOS 7 and 8 (presented as a popover), and iPhone running iOS 7 and 8 (presented full screen)?

I have created a very simple project you may use to try this: [Xcode project zip](http://cl.ly/2N2Y3u3h2n47).

Project setup:

- Universal storyboard targeted to iOS 7+
- Implement Popover Presentation segue
- Implement ability to dismiss popover inside that popover

To encounter the unexpected behavior:

1. Open the provided Xcode project
2. Run the app on iPad iOS 7 Simulator
3. Tap the top cell to present the popover
4. Tap the cell in the popover to dismiss it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you try to handle the popover. To close the popover you should use the `dismissPopoverAnimated` method instead of `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

I think you will have to make more work to complete your task for targeting both iOS versions. The root view controller should have some property to store the created popover with PoppedUpTVC as popover content and the PoppedUpTVC has to ask the root view controller to perform `dismissPopoverAnimated` method on the stored popover to close it.

To get a reference to the popover, try this in `prepareForSegue`:

```
if ([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]]) {
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
    yourDestViewController.propertyToStorePopover = popoverSegue.popoverController;
}
```

Comment: How does one get a reference to the `UIPopoverController` when you're using a Popover Presentation segue? `presentationController` property is only available in iOS 8, there is no `popoverController` property.

Comment: Try to use `prepareForSegue` or perform `init(contentViewController viewController: UIViewController)` and `func presentPopoverFromRect(_ rect: CGRect, inView view: UIView, permittedArrowDirections arrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection, animated animated: Bool)` by code

Comment: hi @Joey - this is exactly a situation I am facing. Are you able to update your question to post what exactly was in your prepareForSegue?

Comment: @Lavanya I've edited the answer with the code I used to get a reference to the popover controller.

Comment: You should also check if that viewController or its parent nav controller is set as rootViewController. if it is, you should set the rootViewController to whatever viewController needs to be the rootViewController after the viewController is dismissed and then dismiss the viewController. You can get access to current rootViewController this way; [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).window.rootViewController